# When developing for GNU Radio, should I use WX GUI or Qt GUI widgets?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm starting to use GNU Radio. Which of the available GUI toolkits should I choose?

Comment: dear close-voter, this is not a recommendation question. Both GUI Frameworks are present in GR, and you can *only* choose between these two. It's a question that arises pretty often in the GNU Radio new users community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always prefer Qt these days – it's the default GUI toolkit for GNU Radio 3.7. No-one develops the WX functionality anymore, and bugfixes haven't been available in a long time. Also, it is well-known that WX has some performance issues, especially on integrated graphic cards.

Furthermore, WXGui has been **completely dropped** from the current (2018) release of GNU Radio, 3.8.