# Could not find any WX GUI blocks in GNU Radio. How to install it?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr

Hey I have installed GNU Radio and I could not find any WX GUI blocks in GNU Radio Companion :-(

How can I install them? I surely need them because most of my projects need WX GUI Blocks…
Hope someone helps me out, and I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When developing for GNU Radio, should I use WX GUI or Qt GUI widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309189/when-developing-for-gnu-radio-should-i-use-wx-gui-or-qt-gui-widgets)

Answer (score 2):

WX is Gone.

GNU Radio 3.8 drops support for WX GUI widgets in favor of QT. If you are using WX widgets in your flow graph, you’d have to replace them with the corresponding QT widgets. For most flow graphs that should be a straight forward drop in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

WX Gui is not supported as of GRC 3.8

https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/GNU_Radio_3.8_OOT_Module_Porting_Guide#WX_is_Gone

Most of the WX instrumentation have some analog in QT

Comment: I have trouble to find an equivalent to the scope plugin. Do you have an idea?